# Staggering database calls for RecyclerView population

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-volley

When does it become necessary to stagger database calls while populating RecyclerViews? Given the nature of RecyclerViews is it even necessary at all? I use the volley library to access my MySQL db.

EDIT: When I open a RecyclerView I need to populate it with information. I store this information in my database.

Let's say I am a player who has played 10,000 'games' and I want to see a list of all the games I've played. When I open up the the Games List, I will see a RecyclerView displaying a list of all the games I've played.

My question is, should I retrieve all 10,000 games at once or only 100 at a time, retrieving more as I scroll through the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "stagger database calls"? I don't see how anything regarding network operations is related to `RecyclerView` at all...

Comment: @RU92Z Can you explain in detail what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I've edited my question to add detail

Comment: Did you try doing both and comparing their performance? I always retrieve all data first and don't notice performance drop but I haven't really handled large data (> 5000).